# Soft question, limit of $n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: limits, soft-question

I was trying to think of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that were, in a sense, small. By that I mean how 'spread out' the terms were. I know this isn't at all concise, but for example, $3\mathbb{Z}$ is 'smaller' (in the manner described above) than say $2\mathbb{Z}$. So this got me thinking, looking at specifically $n\mathbb{Z}$, is there anything meaningful to talk about $\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ ?

Firstly I thought, does this even make sense? Is it just a meaningless thing to consider?

What made intuitive sense is, if we consider the extended reals, that the limit is $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$, but that just seemed somehow not quite right.

Is there any resources available, or anything to talk about limits, or limits alike?

Comment: Have you looked up “density”? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density

Comment: I am familiar with density, but with regards to the limit, is that applicable? If so, how?

Comment: The $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of a sequence of sets are well defined. When they are equal, one can speak of the limit. See [set-theoretic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit). In your example, the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are both the empty set, so one can say that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n\mathbb Z = \emptyset$.

Comment: " but for example, 3Z is 'smaller' (in the manner described above) than say 2Z. So this got me thinking, looking at specifically nZ, is there anything meaningful to talk about limn→∞nZ ?"  Not only do I not think it is meaningful, I don't think it is meaningful to say $3\mathbb Z$ is "smaller" than $2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Bungo correction: the limit is $\{ 0 \}$

Comment: @AlexG. Oops, duh :-) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, cleared up my confusion.

Comment: @Bungo: I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @RobArthan I wasn't sure if my comment was addressing what the OP was really after, but based on his/her latest comment it seems it was helpful, so I'll go ahead and upgrade my comment to an answer.

Comment: In another direction (more topological than the set-theoretic one of @Bungo, which deals kind of poorly with subsets having an empty intersection), you might want to look up the Hausdorff distance. 
In $\mathbb R$, the  Hausdorff  distance between the $n \mathbb Z$ will be infinite, so it is not that interesting. However, in the extended real line, endowed with some bounded metric defining its topology (so that it is isometric to $[-1,1]$, for instance), the sequence does converge to the set $\{\pm \infty\}$ with respect to the Hausdorff distance.

Comment: @J.Darné Nice observation, and perhaps closer to what the OP was looking for. The limit would be $\{\pm \infty, 0\}$, wouldn't it?

Comment: You are right, I was forgetting that $0$ was a "fixed point". Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of a sequence of sets are always defined. When they are equal, one can speak of the limit of the sequence.

The definitions are as follows, for a sequence $(A_n)$ of sets.

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$$
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m$$

In words, $\liminf A_n$ consists of those points that are contained in all $A_n$'s for sufficiently large $n$. And $\limsup A_n$ consists of those points that are contained in infinitely many of the $A_n$'s.

In your case ($A_n = n\mathbb Z$), it's clear that both $\liminf n \mathbb Z$ and $\limsup n \mathbb Z$ contain exactly one point, namely $0$. Therefore,
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} n \mathbb Z = \limsup_{n \to \infty}n \mathbb Z = \{0\}$$
Since the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are equal, it's valid to say that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n \mathbb Z$ exists and equals $\{0\}$.

See [set-theoretic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful to me!